# how fix error protocol with cpanel and go server

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, go, axios, cpanel

I have set up a Go server and front with reactJs in cpanel/linux , I ran the server and everything was fine, but it turns out that when I configure an endpoint with https in my service, it indicates an ssl protocol error, I don't know if it is a configuration problem in my .htaccess

my services in react example:

```js
export const AttendanceService = {
    async getAllAttendance() {
        const res = await axios.get(`${baseUrl}`);
        console.log("debería llegar así:", res.data)
        return res.data;
    },
    async validate(pin) {
        try {
            await axios.get(`${baseUrl}/validate/${pin}`);
        } catch (error) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Error',
                text: error.response.data.message
            });
            console.log(error)
            throw new Error("Error al validar")
        }

    },
    async createArrival(data) {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${baseUrl}/register`, JSON.stringify(data), {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                }
            });
            console.log("debería llegar así:", res.data)
            Swal.fire({
                position: 'center',
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Registro exitoso',
                showConfirmButton: false,
                timer: 1500
            })

        } catch (error) {
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: error.response.data.message
            })
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

routes go:

```js
import (
    "github.com/Edwinfpirajan/Distrifabrica.git/common"
    "github.com/Edwinfpirajan/Distrifabrica.git/controller"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
)

func EchoRoutes(e *echo.Echo) {
    e.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
        AllowOrigins: []string{"*"},
        AllowMethods: []string{"*"},
        AllowHeaders: []string{"*"},
    }))
    e.Use(middleware.LoggerWithConfig(middleware.LoggerConfig{
        Format: "method=${method}, uri=${uri}, status=${status}\n",
    }))

    group := e.Group("/api")

    // LOGIN

    e.POST("/login", controller.Login)
    e.POST("/logout", controller.Logout, common.OnlyAdmin)

    // USER ROUTES

    //ATTENDANCE REGISTER

    group.POST("/attendance/register", controller.SaveRegisterAttendance)
    group.GET("/attendance", controller.GetAllAttendance)
    group.GET("/attendance/validate/:pin", controller.ValidateEmploye)

    // ADMIN ROUTES

    //EMPLOYE MANAGE

    group.GET("/all", controller.GetAll)
    group.POST("/save", controller.SaveEmploye, common.OnlyAdmin)
    group.DELETE("/delete/:id", controller.DeleteEmploye, common.OnlyAdmin)
    group.GET("/find/:id", controller.GetEmploye, common.OnlyAdmin)

    // SCHEDULE MANAGE

    group.GET("/schedule/all", controller.GetAllSchedule, common.OnlyAdmin)
    group.POST("/schedule/save", controller.SaveSchedule, common.OnlyAdmin)
    group.DELETE("/schedule/delete/:id", controller.DeleteSchedule, common.OnlyAdmin)
}
```

and my .htaccess

```js
 RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
       RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
       RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
       RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have tried to solve with thousands of changes, but nothing that succeeds

Comment: this is api rest:
const baseUrl = "https://distriramirez.com.co:8080/api/attendance";